# Import several sheets of many workbooks in R

Tags: r

Im trying to merge a many sheets of many Excel worksbooks and  in one column the name of the sheets:

```
    Path <- 'P3.xlsx'
sheets<-path %>% excel_sheets()
sheets2 <- as.vector(sheets)
df3 <- map_df(sheets, ~ read_excel(path, sheet = .x) %>% 
                mutate(Fecha = as.character(date)), .id = 'sheet_name')

path <- 'P4.xlsx'
sheets<-path %>% excel_sheets()
sheets2 <- as.vector(sheets)
df4 <- map_df(sheets, ~ read_excel(path, sheet = .x) %>% 
                mutate(Fecha = as.character(date)), .id = 'sheet_name')

path <- 'P5.xlsx'
sheets<-path %>% excel_sheets()
sheets2 <- as.vector(sheets)
df5 <- map_df(sheets, ~ read_excel(path, sheet = .x) %>% 
                mutate(Fecha = as.character(date)), .id = 'sheet_name')

dft <- rbind(P3,P4,P5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the `files` and apply the same

```
library(purrr)
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
paths <- str_c("P", 3:5, ".xlsx")
out <- map_dfr(paths, ~ {
            sheets <- .x %>%
              excel_sheets() %>%
              as.vector
            map_df(sheets, ~read_excel(path, sheet = .x) %>% 
                mutate(Fecha = as.character(date)), .id = 'sheet_name')
     }, .id = 'paths_name')
```